# How to add a value to title of a data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to add the sum of two columns in the data frame to the name of the data frame using a for loop. The names_2 list contains the names of the data frames.

```
for(i in names_2){
  total_1 = sum(i$V3)
  total_2 = sum(i$V4)
  i <- paste(i,total_1,total_2,sep = "_")
}
```

I get an error because it doesn't recognize that I am trying to call a data frame. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
#Get data in a list
list_df <- mget(names_2)
#Sum the two columns and paste it together
total_title <- sapply(list_df, function(x) paste(colSums(x[c('V3', 'V4')]), collapse = '_'))
#Rename the list
names(list_df) <- paste(names_2, total_title, sep = '_')
#Create new dataframes with new names
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```